# Get a process ID in C by name

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I'm trying to get a process ID by a process name (for example, `notepad.exe`), but previous solutions on Stack Overflow don't seem to work properly. Here is what I've tried:

```
DWORD FindProcessId(const char *processname)
{
    HANDLE hProcessSnap;
    PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;
    DWORD result = NULL;

    // Take a snapshot of all processes in the system.
    hProcessSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hProcessSnap) return(FALSE);

    // Retrieve information about the first process,
    // and exit if unsuccessful
    if (!Process32First(hProcessSnap, &pe32))
    {
        CloseHandle(hProcessSnap);          // Clean the snapshot object
        return(FALSE);
    }

    do
    {
        if (0 == _stricmp(processname, pe32.szExeFile))
        {
            result = pe32.th32ProcessID;
            break;
        }
    } while (Process32Next(hProcessSnap, &pe32));

    CloseHandle(hProcessSnap);

    return result;
}
```

I pass in "notepad.exe" and confirm that it is running on my system, and that the application is running as Administrator with the correct privileges required. Elevation is done like this:

```
        if (GetModuleFileName(NULL, szPath, ARRAYSIZE(szPath)))
        {
            // Launch itself as administrator.
            sei.lpVerb = TEXT("runas");
            sei.lpFile = szPath;
            sei.hwnd = NULL;
            sei.nShow = SW_NORMAL;

            if (!ShellExecuteEx(&sei))
            {
                MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("The program needs to be elevated to work properly."), APP_TITLE, MB_OK);
                return -1;
            }
        }
        return 0;
```

It never finds the process ID - returns Null every time.

This is using C, not C++.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need admin privileges to enumerate names and pids of all running processes.

Comment: @user2345215 That's out of the scope of the question. Regardless of if it is elevated or not, it still fails to find the process.

Comment: Debugging the program, it seems to end at the catch `if (!Process32First(hProcessSnap, &pe32))` - why would this be false?

Comment: What's the getlasterror?

Comment: @user2345215 Fixed, see my answer

Comment: Check the charset for your project settings: is it unicode or mbcs?  Change  stricmp to _tcsicmp.  If it is changed, it doesn't matter what the project setting is.  If you want to use stricmp then the charset for the project should be mbcs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is to simply set the `pe32.dwSize` after getting the process snapshot. Complete fixed code here:

```
DWORD FindProcessId(const char *processname)
{
    HANDLE hProcessSnap;
    PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;
    DWORD result = 0;

    // Take a snapshot of all processes in the system.
    hProcessSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hProcessSnap) return(FALSE);

    pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32); // <----- IMPORTANT

    // Retrieve information about the first process,
    // and exit if unsuccessful
    if (!Process32First(hProcessSnap, &pe32))
    {
        CloseHandle(hProcessSnap);          // clean the snapshot object
        printf("!!! Failed to gather information on system processes! \n");
        return(0);
    }

    do
    {
        printf("Checking process %ls\n", pe32.szExeFile);
        if (0 == strcmp(processname, pe32.szExeFile))
        {
            result = pe32.th32ProcessID;
            break;
        }
    } while (Process32Next(hProcessSnap, &pe32));

    CloseHandle(hProcessSnap);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Also, if you are interested, I have a code for this using only `NtQuerySystemInformation`. I think it's more elegant alternative to the sloppy toolhelp32 functions. But I'd understand if you didn't want to link against ntdll.

Comment: @user2345215 If you have an implementation please share!

Comment: Well, it's actually in c++, not c, so I'll just post a pastebin link here: http://pastebin.com/LNf4XHJs

Comment: Anyway, I cut it down a little bit. It was a little bit bigger than I imagined and I didn't want to introduce too many internal structures. But `ImageName` is not really a plain `WCHAR` there, it's a `UNICODE_STRING`, there are two USHORT values just before the `ImageName` and the first of them is the length of the string. It's probably null terminated, but I wouldn't rely on that. It's probably not worth it to do all this unless you want some other info in that structure that's not normally available. (and I hid it all under `unused`)

Comment: Thank you for posting your answer.  It is a very useful function.  (+1).  Id like to offer 2 suggestions though, initializing a `DWORD` to `NULL` throws a warning.  Changing `DWORD result = NULL;` to: `DWORD result = 0;` suppresses the warning.  It follows that the line: `return(NULL);` should be: `return(0);`