# What is the C version of "Processes.GetProcessesByName("PROCESSNAME")"?

Tags: c, windows, process, console-application, taskmanager

I have used Process.GetProcessesByName("PROCESSNAME") before in C# to check if a specific project is running.

I have to create a C program for an older embedded version of Windows XP which can only run when another program is also running.

How can I check if the program is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to get a [Get a process id in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20874381/get-a-process-id-in-c-by-name)  might be helpful to you.

This example uses `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);` which can be used to get a snapshot for different processes. (I am assuming you know the name of the process you are checking)

Answer (score 1):

Might be a dup of:
[How can I get a process handle by its name in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865152/how-can-i-get-a-process-handle-by-its-name-in-c)

And either way, this example that enumerates all processes in the system should get you started:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682623(v=vs.85).aspx

- Tim